# C++ I can't update a vector from within a function

Tags: c++, function, vector, structure

I think there's something basic I'm missing here but I have a vector of a structure I made called 'Event' called eventTable that I'm trying to access from within a function.  I'm getting this error: "Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void push_back(const Event &)"  Any suggestions?

```
struct Event {
    enum TYPE {
    Arrival,
    CPUBurstCompletion,
    IOCompletion,
    TimerExpired
  };
  double time;
  TYPE type;
  Event(Event::TYPE type, double time)
      : type(type),
        time(time) {}
};

vector<Event> eventTable;

void createEvent(Event::TYPE type, double time){
    Event newEvent(Event::TYPE type, double time);
    eventTable.push_back(newEvent);
}
```

Comment: This reminds me of the MVP, except it really isn't.

Comment: The most likely cause of this problem is a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include the types.  You want to construct an object, not declare a function.  This constructs an object:

```
Event newEvent(type, time);
```

Comment: "You are constructing an object, not declaring a function" - nice ambiguity... reads either way depending on whether "are" means what the existing code is doing or what the intent is.

Comment: I will edit my answer for the benefit of those who do not possess a brain.

Answer (score 1):

```
Event newEvent(Event::TYPE type, double time);
```

This is not to create an object of `Event` class. The vector `eventTable` stores objects of `Event`, however, you are not providing objects of `Event` in your current way. You were declaring a function.

Try:

```
Event newEvent(type, time);
```